# No GUI appearing, using AWT and Swing

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and beginning to build things with a GUI.  The book I'm using gave me this code to enter and I did but nothing appeared.  I have read another question with an answer that mentioned issues with overridable method calls but I'm not sure that has much to do with this.

Here is the code from the book:

```
enter code here
package com.java24hours;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Crisis extends JFrame {
    JButton panicButton;
    JButton dontPanicButton;
    JButton blameButton;
    JButton mediaButton;
    JButton saveButton;

public Crisis () {
    super("Crisis");
    setLookAndFeel();
    setSize(348, 128);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(flo);
    panicButton = new JButton("Panic");
    dontPanicButton = new JButton("Don't Panic");
    blameButton = new JButton("Blame Others");
    mediaButton = new JButton("Notify the Media");
    saveButton = new JButton("Save Yourself");
    add(panicButton);
    add(dontPanicButton);
    add(blameButton);
    add(mediaButton);
    add(saveButton);
    setVisible(true);


}

private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
            );
        }   catch (Exception exc) {
            //ignore error
        }

    }
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Crisis frame = new Crisis();
    }

}
```

The overridable methods are the "setXXXXX" and "add(XXXX)" methods if this is relevant.

The builds are successful in the lower window of NetBeans so it seems like the code runs okay but it produces nothing else on the screen.

Comment: are you sure **running** and not just **building**? This code works for me (but no Netbeans here)

Comment: Please provide some feedback on that comment, and if the answer(s) helped.

Comment: Carlos Heuberger I'm running it for sure and it's on a Mac if that helps.  What kind of environment did you run it in? IDE & OS?

Comment: I just copied your input to a local file, compiled and ran from the command line, and it all worked fine. That is on MacOs with Oracle Java version "1.8.0_151". I suggested you try to use javac/java on the command line yourself for now. Besides, this should actually be closed as not reproducable ...

Comment: That's not code for Netbeans. That should work for command line compiling. For Netbeans, use the Designer to build the GUI and add the controls (buttons, etc.) where you want them. Netbeans writes the code for you. Try my guide to making a GUI in Netbeans. http://philofjava.webstarts.com/

Comment: Phil Longnecker, I am learning to build them without using any kind of drag and drop or other methods.  Second, how is this not code for Netbeans? Is it not an IDE with a compiler and everything needed to write and run a program?